# AJAX request returning 401 error in c# aspx page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to make this request work but have not succeeded. Here is my code to call the function:

Mypage.aspx.cs:

```cs
[WebMethod]
public static string doSomething(int id)
{
    return "hello";
}
```

HTML side Mypage.aspx:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Mypage.aspx/doSomething",
    data: "{'id':'1'}",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    headers: {
        "Authorization": 'Bearer <%: Token %>'
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var returnedstring = data.d;
        var jsondata = $.parseJSON(data.d);
    }
});
```

Despite including `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`, I receive the following error response:

```json
{
    "Message": "Authentication failed.",
    "StackTrace": null,
    "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException"
}
```

When I use `Content-Type: "text/json"`, the function returns two requests: one of them shows a redirect status of 301, and the second returns the full page. The images below show the requests.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The 301 is occurring because your URI is HTTP instead of HTTPS.  So the library method is automatically redirecting from http to https.

Comment: Remove the authorizing from your ajax call. If the user can use the current web page, then your jQuery ajax call will just work, and no authentication or tokens is required.